# IntelliJ "Import Data from File..." - cannot select file

Tags: intellij-idea, import, datagrip

Using IntelliJ 2020 & 2019, I am unable to select a file when I attempt to "Import data from file...":

1. Go to data source
2. Right click on it
3. Select "Import Data from File..."
4. When the folder window opens, I am unable to select any files

See image:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For me, it actually turned out that my Mac security settings was prohibiting access to the files.